# $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^+ ( \exists M \in \mathbb{Z}^+ ( x > 1/M > 0))$: Cauchy Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

**Synopsis**

I'm sure this question can be found elsewhere on this website, but I haven't yet found a perspective though that uses the construction of the reals through Cauchy sequences to prove this statement. The reason why I'm using Cauchy sequences to prove this is because my textbook (*Tao Analysis 1*) builds up the reals first before delving into the more well known properties of it (like the Axiom of Completeness). I would like to ask the community here just to help verify the validity of my proof.

*Note that the definitions Tao uses are often non-standard and peculiar. So in my proof, I'll try my best to highlight any definitions I use and expand them out. Also note that we've already proved that for every rational $q$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $N \leq q < N+1$.*

**Exercise**

> Show that for any positive real number $x>0$ there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $x > 1/N > 0$.

**Proof**

Since $x$ is a positive real number, $x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_n$ for some rational sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ positively bounded away from zero. In other words, there exists a rational $c > 0$ such that $a_n \geq c$ for all $n \geq 1$. Because $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, we know that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $N \geq 1$ such that for each $j,k \geq N$, $|a_j - a_k| \leq \epsilon$. Now take $\epsilon = c/2$ and its corresponding $N$. Then $a_N - \epsilon > 0$. Now construct a new sequence $(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that if $n \leq N$, then $b_n = a_N$, and if $n > N$, then $b_n = a_n$. Since for all $j,k > N$, $-\epsilon \leq a_j - a_k \leq \epsilon$, it is clear that for all $n \geq 1$, $a_N - \epsilon \leq b_n \leq a_N + \epsilon$. Now we wish to find some integer $M > 0$ such that $1/M < a_N - \epsilon$. So we must find some integer $M$ such that $M > 1/(a_N - \epsilon)$. But we know that such an integer exists by a previous proposition, and since $1/M < a_N - \epsilon \leq b_n$ for all $n \geq 1$, we can conclude that $0 < 1/M \leq x$. If $1/M < x$, then the exercise is proven. If $1/M =x$, just take $M+1$. Then the exercise is satisfied. So either way, we have found a positive integer $M$ such that $x > 1/N > 0$.

Comment: Oh, sorry if this was confusing. We are defining real numbers as limits of sequences of rationals. So if $x$ is irrational, then $a_n = x$ for all $n$ would not be a rational Cauchy sequence.

Comment: You are using the variable name $N$ for two different things.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Lemme change that really quick ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it clearer by specifying that $x$ is the limit of a **rational** sequence. You also need a bit more detail about how that sequence is bounded away from $0$: there are an $\epsilon>0$ and an $n_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $a_n\ge 2\epsilon$ for each $n\ge n_0$. Now use the fact that the sequence is Cauchy to say that there is an $n_1\ge n_0$ such that $|a_j-a_k|\le\epsilon$ whenever $j,k\ge n_1$: this ensures that $a_{n_1}-\epsilon>0$, since $a_{n_1}\ge 2\epsilon$.

Now define the $b_n$ as before: $b_n=a_{n_1}$ if $n\le n_1$, and $b_n=a_n$ otherwise. Your argument that $a_{n_1}-\epsilon\le b_n\le a_{n_1}+\epsilon$ for all $n\ge 1$ is fine, but after that you have a problem: all of a sudden you’re using $N$ for two different integers, my $n_1$ and a new one that I’m going to call $m$. What you want now is some positive integer $m$ such that $\frac1m<a_{n_1}-\epsilon$ or, equivalently, $m>\frac1{a_{n_1}-\epsilon}$. Then you can argue that $\frac1m<a_{n_1}-\epsilon\le b_n$ for all $n\ge 1$ and conclude that $0<\frac1m\le x$. At that point there’s really no need to split the argument into cases depending on whether that last inequality is strict: you might as well just observe that $0<\frac1{m+1}<\frac1m\le x$.

Comment: I've fixed my proof. Would you be willing to check it? However, I do want to apologize that I didn't use your definition of a sequence bounded away from zero because my textbook already has a specific definition for it, and I wanted to keep it consistent.

Comment: @mijucik: That definition is fine, but you you’re not making use of it, and as a result your choice of $N$ is circular. How do you know that you can pick an $\epsilon$ small enough so that $a_N-\epsilon>0$ when $N$ **depends on** the $\epsilon$ that you pick? Instead, do what I did (in a slight disguise): let $\epsilon=\frac{c}2$, and choose $N\ge 1$ so that $|a_j-a_k|<\epsilon$ whenever $j,k\ge N$. Now you **know** that $a_N-\epsilon>a_N-c\ge 0$. After that you’re okay again.

Comment: Oh ok! Lemme fix that really quick.

Comment: I hope it's without error now...

Comment: @mijucik: Yep, looks good. (Sorry: I really should have said something explicitly about that circularity problem in my answer instead of just fixing it without commenting on it.)

Comment: No, I understand it. On a side note, It's great to see you again. I'm not sure if you know this, but you've answered and checked a lot of my proofs back when I was focusing on set theory, and so it's amazing that you're now answering my questions on analysis as well. Thank you!

Comment: @mijucik: Yours actually is one of the names that I recognize, so yes, I did remember. And as long as the material stays towards the topological end of analysis I’ll probably be able to answer a fair number of questions. You’re welcome: it’s always a pleasure to work with someone who asks reasonable questions and engages seriously with the material!